# an algorithm that deletes data in a table instead of the extract

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I coded an algorithm using the Hibernate framework of course to browse a table and return multiple rows.

However, this algorithm erases the contents of the table then the return of this Query is **null**.

```
ArrayList<Compte> list = null;
    try {
    Session  session = HibernateUtils.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = s.createQuery("from Compte where compte_utilisateuridentifiant = :y");
    q.setString("y", identifiant);
    list = (ArrayList<Compte>) q.list();
    tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {

    } finally {

    }

    for (Compte c: list)
        System.out.println("[rib] = " + c.getRib() + "\t" +
                "[title] = " + c.getLibelle() + "\t" +
                "[dateC] = " + c.getDateCréation() + "\t");
    return list;
```

Here is the CFG File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!--  Paramètres de connexion à la base de données -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bh</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">esct</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Comportement pour la conservation des tables -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Activation : affichage en console, commentées et formatées -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <!-- Fichiers à mapper -->
    <mapping class="tn.bh.jpa.Compte" />
    <mapping class="tn.bh.jpa.Mouvement_Compte" />
    <mapping class="tn.bh.jpa.Solde" />
    <mapping class="tn.bh.jpa.User" />
    <mapping class="tn.bh.jpa.Virement" />
```

Can someone help me please ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Can you paste the cfg file? Also close the session after committing the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing below property might help:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Reason: I think you are running this query by rebooting hibernate and since the property is set to create, once hibernate reboots, it create the complete schema again and your query gets executed. Since there is no data(because of the fresh schema creation, and no inserts/saves to table before this query execution), you end up getting no result.

Note that i am presuming something here.